# d3: assigning a color to a specific value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I process data for a pie chart, I combine all small values into 'Other'.  The chart is being colored using d3.scale.category20.  How can I assign 'Other' to a specific color (light gray) from the color set and have other values assigned using the default method?

**Update**: I'm looking for an idiomatic D3 solution if there is one.  Anything else I can hack up myself.

Comment: Can you provide just the part that draws the paths? So I can show you how to do it. Also, please show how "other" is created.

Comment: I'm pretty much using the code from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235).  Except I changed the color variable to be `d3.scale.category20`.  'Other' is calculated in python and passed in with the rest of the data as another (last) row.

Comment: I deleted my answer, once it was not helping you. As I said, the best approach is just creating your own ordinal scale, defining the domain. Have a look in what Bostock wrote here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/jsEmhdT9wiU/Xv3Mqql75vYJ

Comment: So, according to the creator of D3 himself, apparently there is no idiomatic solution.

Comment: bummer.  Thanks for checking.  Do you mind providing a link to where he said that?

Comment: It's 2 comments above, it's not showing up to you? The question this user made is different from yours, but Bostock's answer is what matters: you have to map the domain beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `d3.scale.category20` without grey:

```
var myCategory20Colors = [
  0x1f77b4, 0xaec7e8,
  0xff7f0e, 0xffbb78,
  0x2ca02c, 0x98df8a,
  0xd62728, 0xff9896,
  0x9467bd, 0xc5b0d5,
  0x8c564b, 0xc49c94,
  0xe377c2, 0xf7b6d2,
  0xbcbd22, 0xdbdb8d,
  0x17becf, 0x9edae5
].map(function(x) {
    var value = x + "";
    return d3.rgb(value >> 16, value >> 8 & 0xff, value & 0xff).toString();
});

var myCategory20 = d3.scale.ordinal().range(myCategory20Colors);

var original = d3.scale.category20();

console.log(original("x"), original("y"));

console.log(myCategory20("x"), myCategory20("y"));
// they produce the same result #1f77b4 #aec7e8
```

(I removed `0x7f7f7f, 0xc7c7c7,`) from the list, you can replace them with your own colors as well.

Then you can simply check for the data when doing coloring.

```
  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
         if(d.yourRowName == "Other") {
           return "grey";
         } else {
           return myCategory20(d.data.age);
         }
      });
```

Comment: This will not work because one of the non-other categories will also be assigned gray from the category20 set.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've mentioned up-front that I'm looking for an idiomatic D3 solution.  I already have a hack in-place :)

Comment: @DmitryB. no problem, I learnt a lot of d3 internals from answering this question actually :)